# Pip failed to install wheels in 3.8.12-slim-bullseye in armv7 architecture

Tags: python, docker, pip

When I try to build an image from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.12-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR test

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -U \
        pip\
        setuptools\
        wheel
RUN     pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src .
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" , "main.py" ]
```

The build fails in the step where it has to install `wheel` the exception is `Operation not permitted`. I am running this command in
a rasberry-pi, If I use a machine with x86_64 architecture everything works fine.

```
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
  Attempting uninstall: wheel
    Found existing installation: wheel 0.37.0
    Uninstalling wheel-0.37.0:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/METADATA', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/METADATA', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/LICENSE.txt', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/LICENSE.txt', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/top_level.txt', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/top_level.txt', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/WHEEL', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/WHEEL', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/INSTALLER', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/INSTALLER', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/REQUESTED', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/REQUESTED', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/RECORD', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/RECORD', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted')]
```

This is the full output from `docker built`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.282MB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.8.12-slim-bullseye
 ---> 6af871082c8c
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR test
 ---> Running in aab6bfab5ffd
Removing intermediate container aab6bfab5ffd
 ---> 6506db067c9d
Step 3/7 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> 93a3a59af85d
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -U   pip     setuptools      wheel
 ---> Running in b3c4b36bd1de
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (21.2.4)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (57.5.0)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-60.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (958 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.37.0)
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
  Attempting uninstall: wheel
    Found existing installation: wheel 0.37.0
    Uninstalling wheel-0.37.0:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/METADATA', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/METADATA', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/LICENSE.txt', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/LICENSE.txt', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/top_level.txt', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/top_level.txt', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/WHEEL', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/WHEEL', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/INSTALLER', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/INSTALLER', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/REQUESTED', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/REQUESTED', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/RECORD', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/RECORD', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted'), ('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel-0.37.0.dist-info/', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~heel-0.37.0.dist-info', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted')]

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -U  pip     setuptools      wheel' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Architecture: armv71
Docker version: 20.10.11

Comment: Does it work without updating `wheel`?

Comment: If I just do `pip install -r requiremets.txt` one of the dependencies install fails for a different permission reason. If I try to update pip before installing, it also fails with the same permission issue that this thread but instead of wheel is pip.